# Fastest way to transform WKT in python

Tags: python, pyproj

Is it possible to use pyproj to transform WKT without creating geometry objects such shapely geometry, GEOS geometry or OGR geometry.

If not what is the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. 
In that case, you need to transform each point separately. First parse WKT and extract point coordinates, then loop over coordinates and perform transformation like:

```
import pyproj

srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:%i' % epsg_in, preserve_units=True)
dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:%i' % epsg_out, preserve_units=True)

x_out,y_out = pyproj.transform(srcProj, dstProj, x_in, y_in)
```

Comment: alright, but parsing and reconstructing WKT is not that easy for multipolygon for instance

Comment: you might want to take a look at shapely http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#well-known-formats

Answer (score 4):

Also check out Lars Butler's https://github.com/larsbutler/geomet, a pure Python WKT/WKB <-> GeoJSON converter.

Comment: Yes, I am using it to convert fiona f['geometry'] to WKT. Thank you @sgillies